# how to calculate after carriage return is passed through TextWatcher

Tags: android, carriage-return, textwatcher

So I'm building an android app and I'm really struggling to get my textwatcher to wait for a carriage return before calling calculate(). I'm also struggling to remove the carriage return before passing the value through to calculate.

I also commented some code out to use one textwatcher for both edit texts, but included it in the second box. If it's easier to tackle it that way I'd love help getting that working as well.

Any help would be great! thanks!

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final NumberFormat percentFormat =
        NumberFormat.getInstance();

private double minCompleted = 0.0;//min completed by user
private double secCompleted = 0.0;//sec completed by user
private double min = 0.0;//min allotted
private double sec = 0.0;//sec alloted
private TextView minCompletedTextView;//shows min completed
private TextView secCompletedTextView;//shows sec completed
private TextView progressTextView;//shows progress
private EditText minEditText;
private EditText secEditText;


//called when activity is first created
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//call superclasses version
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//inflate the GUI

    //get references to programmatically manipulated textviews
    minCompletedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minCompletedTextView);
    secCompletedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secCompletedTextView);
    progressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTextView);
    minEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minEditText);
    secEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secEditText);


    //set minEditText's TextWatcher
    EditText minEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minEditText);
    minEditText.addTextChangedListener(minEditTextWatcher);

    //set secEditText's TextWatcher
    EditText secEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secEditText);
    secEditText.addTextChangedListener(secEditTextWatcher);

    //set minCompletedSeekerbar's OnSeekerChangeListener
    SeekBar minCompletedSeekBar =
            (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.minCompletedSeekBar);
    minCompletedSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarListener);

    //set secCompletedSeekerbar's OnSeekerChangeListener
    SeekBar secCompletedSeekBar =
            (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.secCompletedSeekBar);
    secCompletedSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarListener);

    //set progressSeekerbar's OnSeekerChangeListener
    SeekBar progressSeekBar =
            (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progressSeekBar);
    progressSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarListener);
}

//calculate and display total progress completed
private void calculate() {
    //display in minCompletedTextView
    minCompletedTextView.setText(percentFormat.format(minCompleted));

    //display in secCompletedTextView
    secCompletedTextView.setText(percentFormat.format(secCompleted));

    //time allotted, time used and progress
    double completedtime = (minCompleted*60) + secCompleted;
    double totaltime = (min*60) + sec;
    double timeleft = (completedtime / totaltime)*100;
    int intVal = (int) Math.floor(timeleft);

    //show seekbar progress
    SeekBar progressSeekBar =
            (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progressSeekBar);
    progressSeekBar.setProgress(intVal);

    //if statement to max out progress at 100%
    if (intVal <= 100){
        progressTextView.setText("Progress "+"\n" + intVal +"%");
    }else if (intVal > 100){
        progressTextView.setText("Progress "+"\n" + "100" +"%");
    }

}

//listener object for the SeekBar's progress change events
private final SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarListener =
        new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            //update completed min, then call calculate
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                if (seekBar.getId() == R.id.minCompletedSeekBar) {
                    minCompleted = progress; // set based on progress
                    calculate(); //calculate and display progress
                } else if (seekBar.getId() == R.id.secCompletedSeekBar) {
                    secCompleted = progress;
                    calculate();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

        };

//listener object for the minEditText's text-changed events
private final TextWatcher minEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    //called when the user modifies min allotment
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (s.length()>0 && s.charAt(start + count - 1) == '\n') {
                minEditText.getText().replace(start + count - 1, start + count, "");
                s = minEditText.getEditableText();
                //enterKey=true;
            }
            try {
                min = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                minEditText.setText(s);

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                minEditText.setText("");
                min = 0;
            }
            calculate();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(
            CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
};

private final TextWatcher secEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    //called when the user modifies sec allotment
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (s.length()>0 && s.charAt(start + count - 1) == '\n') {
            secEditText.getText().replace(start + count - 1, start + count, "");
            s = secEditText.getEditableText();
            //enterKey=true;
        }
        try {
            sec = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            secEditText.setText(s);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            secEditText.setText("");
            sec = 0;
        }
        calculate();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(
            CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
};
```

}

```
private final TextWatcher timeTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        boolean enterKey = false;

        if(s==minEditText.getEditableText()) {
            if (s.length()>0 && s.charAt(start + count - 1) == '\n') {
                minEditText.getText().replace(start + count - 1, start + count, "");
                s = minEditText.getEditableText();
                enterKey=true;
            }
            try {
                min = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                minEditText.setText(s);

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                minEditText.setText("");
                min = 0;
            }
        }


        if(s==secEditText.getEditableText()) {
            if (s.length()>0 && s.charAt(start + count - 1) == '\n') {
                secEditText.getText().replace(start + count - 1, start + count, "");
                s = secEditText.getEditableText();
                enterKey=true;
            }
            try {
                sec = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                secEditText.setText(s);

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                secEditText.setText("");
                sec = 0;
            }
        }

       if(enterKey) {
           calculate();
            //startTimer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

};
```

Comment: The CharSequence will have the current entered text so it seems unnecessary to work with the start/before/count in your case.  Use 's.toString().indexOf("\n") != -1' and 's.toString().substring(0,s.indexOf("\n")' to check if it's there and to get everything up to it.  Also, "\n" is technically a newline.  Finally your "s == ..." need to be a string comparison not a equality test.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest problem is you call `TextView.setText` inside its `TextView.TextWatcher`. As the document in `TextWatcher.beforeTextChanged/onTextChanged/afterTextChanged`, you should **NEVER** change text during this callback.

```
/**
 * This method is called to notify you that, within <code>s</code>,
 * the <code>count</code> characters beginning at <code>start</code>
 * have just replaced old text that had length <code>before</code>.
 * It is an error to attempt to make changes to <code>s</code> from
 * this callback.
 */
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count);
```

This problem can be solved by `removeTextChangedListener` then change text and `addTextChangedListener` again but it is a little bit heavy.

Another workaround is add a status tag in TextWatcher which is low cost to performance.

An example for changing text in `afterTextChanged`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        boolean isEditing=false;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!isEditing) {
                isEditing =true;
                // Doing your changes with editText.
                editText.setText("new text or addition");
                isEditing =false;
            }
        }
    });
```